# Detecting which IP address is receiving socket traffic

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

How can I detect which IP address is receiving an incoming packet when my windows service code works on multiple IP addresses on a public server?

I'm using an `UdpSocket` to listen incoming packets.

This is my server application code:

```
ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
EndPoint ServerEndPoint =   new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
ServerSocket.Bind(ServerEndPoint);
ServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(_arrReceivedDataBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE - 1, SocketFlags.None, ref ServerEndPoint, DoReceiveFromClient, ServerSocket);

private void DoReceiveFromClient(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)
{
            _ClientSocket = (Socket)AsyncResult.AsyncState;
            EndPoint ClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            int intMsgLen = _ClientSocket.EndReceiveFrom(AsyncResult, ref ClientEndPoint);

            String strMessage = "Hello From Server!"
            byte[] arrData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMessage);
            ServerSocket.SendTo(arrData, arrData.Length, SocketFlags.None, _ClientSocket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are listening on `INADDR_ANY` on a system which has multiple IP addresses on the same subnet, then there is no reliable way to tell which physical interface actually received the packet.

You also cannot easily control which interface will be used when you send a reply packet back to the original sender.  The OS may choose whichever source address it considers the default for that route.  If that is different than the original sender's destination address, then NAT or firewall devices may block your reply.  Problems also arise if two different physical interfaces are being used in parallel as a poor-man's bonded link.  In that case, all replies may be routed over only one of the interfaces, leaving the other underutilized.

A way around this is to enumerate all interfaces, bind a socket to each one individually, then tag incoming packets so that you know which socket to reply upon.  The challenge there is that the interfaces may change at any time, which can be difficult to detect.